# Hidden checkbox values are not included in jQuery .serialize()

Tags: jquery, forms, serialization, checkbox, datatables

I am using the jQuery plugin "DataTables" which helps me display large paginated tables of data including many rows with checkboxes. All works as expected in Chrome, but in IE8 when I serialize the DataTable form containing checkboxes, only the checkboxes that are visiable are serialized. In Datatables, the paginations allows you to select checkboxes and move to a different page of results (say 11-19 instead of 1-9) yet maintain the selection previously made on a different page of results.

When I use $("#theForm").serialize() in a $.post call, only the visible checkboxes are included. This is not the case in Chrome where the entire list of selected checkboxes including hidden checkboxes are found with .serialize().

This situation seems like it must have happened before to other people, let me know if there is a solution! Thanks!

Comment: http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/6102/post-multiple-selected-rows-to-php-non-server-side-processing/p1 and http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/select_rows.html

Comment: `jQuery.serialize()` tries to do the same thing as submitting the form would. When you submit a form, hidden inputs (`display: none`, not `type=hidden`) are skipped. Maybe you can show everything, call `serialize()`, then hide again.

Comment: I need a method to create copies of the data in the form of hidden input fields, then remove them from the DOM once submission is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to unhide the checkboxes serialize, and re-hide them. This does not result in a bunch of checkboxes appearing and disappearing because it happens so fast.