# Getting values of hidden checkboxes jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with several checkboxes. Some values need to be true by default so i have made them hidden as:

```
 <input type=checkbox name="<%= _key %>" checked="checked" style="display:none" />
```

To retrieve all values i'm doing:

```
 var form_data = {}   
 $('form').find("input").each(function(i, e) { 
        if (e.checked)  
           form_data[e.name] = e.value; 
    });
```

But the hidden input fields are not coming. What am I doing wrong? How can I correct it?

Also im using underscore.js but i don't think this problem has to do anything with it.

Comment: I found this one solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870463/hidden-checkbox-values-are-not-included-in-jquery-serialize However i think this is not the right way of solving it!

Comment: Why don't you use hidden field instead?

Comment: @ThinkDifferent yeah that can be done but the question is why is this not working?

Comment: @singhshivam simply it should work, check this http://jsfiddle.net/jcvC2/1/

Comment: Try `e.prop('checked')`

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity you can do this:

```
$(function(){ // put the code in doc ready
   var form_data = {}   
   $('form').find(":checkbox:checked").each(function(i, e) { 
       form_data[e.name] = e.value; 
   });
});
```

---

So here i am suggesting you to just loop through the checked elems and put names & values in the javascript object.

---

But if you are interested in only hidden checked checkboxes `$('form').find(":checkbox:checked:hidden")`.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine on jsfiddle but i dont know why its not working on my app

Comment: okay wrap the code with `$(function(){...put the code });` doc ready block;

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this jQuery way.

```
$('form').find("input").each(function(i, e) {
var jEl = $(this);
if(jEl.is(":checked"))
    alert(1);
    alert(jEl.attr("name"));
});
```